# What is the keyboard shortcut for opening the file explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, explorer

I've been searching and I can't find the keyboard short cut to open the file explorer in Eclipse (I am mainly using PHP and Java Eclipse). I like to close the file explorer from time to time to give myself more space to see my code and then reopen it when I need to navigate to a different folder/file.

This would be very useful and would save a lot of unhandy hand movement!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you right:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - for mac) and then press <kbd>E</kbd> will open PHP explorer

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (<kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - for mac) to get list of available hotkeys.

Comment: Is there anyway to close it with the keyboard?

Comment: press esc, if it's not maximazed

Answer (score 2):

To navigate a file in **your system** from eclipse,where file actually *stored*:

Alt + Shift + W + X (In Windows OS)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a shortcut by yourself. Go to `window/general/preferences/keys`, search for command related to your explorer view and assign shortcut to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in Windows. It will prompt the open file exporer. So that you can browse and open a file you want..

Answer (score 0):

To open any view (and a range of other things as well in eclipse for instance preference pages) you can use the Quick Access dialog. Type `Ctrl + 3` and then type the name of the view you wish to open.